# How to get orignal manufacturer data in flutter BLE using flutter_blue

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an app to read BLE beacons using flutter and I am using flutter_blue when I scan the device and got the manufacturer data as `{256:[0,0,0,16,1,57,33,18,0,0,154,10,0,0,94,0]}`

the device manufacturer told me to device data like :

KCBAdvDataManufacturerData = `<.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. be 21 01 00 50 08 00 00 5e ..>`

when I scan the device using readily available BLE app like BLE Hero I got the manufacturer data as 00 01 08 1e ac a2 00 37 8f 35 05 00 f0 08 00 00 4b 00

i have no idea how can i convert

`{256:[0,0,0,16,1,57,33,18,0,0,154,10,0,0,94,0]}`

To

`00 01 08 1e ac a2 00 37 8f 35 05 00 f0 08 00 00 4b 00`

Answer (score 6):

As it says in the flutter_blue documentation, [manufactureData](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue/latest/flutter_blue/AdvertisementData/manufacturerData.html) is returned as a Map object and you appear to be asking how to get the value for the Map key/value pair.

This is covered in the following tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_map.htm

The general case is `map_name[key]`. In your example the key is `256` and the map_name is `KCBAdvDataManufacturerData` so to get the list, it would be `KCBAdvDataManufacturerData[256]`

This looks linked to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572951/how-to-get-desired-values-from-ble-manufacturer-data-flutter), so to put that in a more complete example:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

var bleData = {256:[0,0,0,16,1,57,33,18,0,0,154,10,0,0,94,0]};
main() {
  parseManufacturerData(bleData);
}
parseManufacturerData(data) { 
  var manufacturerData = Uint8List.fromList(data[256]);
  var pressure = ByteData.sublistView(manufacturerData, 6, 10);
  var temperature = ByteData.sublistView(manufacturerData, 10, 14);
  var battery = ByteData.sublistView(manufacturerData, 14, 15);
  print("Pressure: ${pressure.getUint32(0, Endian.little)/100} psi");
  print("Temperature: ${temperature.getUint32(0, Endian.little)/100} \u{00B0}C");
  print("Battery: ${battery.getUint8(0)} %");
}
```

When I run this at https://dart.dev/#try-dart it gives:

```
Pressure: 46.41 psi
Temperature: 27.14 °C
Battery: 94 %
```

I have no way of testing the following code, but this how I would try modifying the *Scan for devices* example at https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue/latest/index.html:

```dart
// Start scanning
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

// Listen to scan results
var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
    // do something with scan results
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
        print('${r.advertisementData.manufacturerData}');
        // Pass it to our previous function
        parseManufacturerData(r.advertisementData.manufacturerData)
    }
});

// Stop scanning
flutterBlue.stopScan();
```

I am expecting the key value in the `advertisementData.manufacturerData` to be the [Company ID](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers/). The thing that is confusing me, is the value of decimal 256 in your example is for *TomTom International BV* which might not be the device sending the pressure, temperature, and battery values. If that is the case, then you will need some logic in the code to only call `parseManufacturerData` if it is the device of interest.