# Flutter Eddystone beacon detection

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, eddystone, eddystone-url

Is there any Flutter package available that can listen for Eddystone UID beacons and Eddystone-URLs?

I have been looking at various packages such as [beacons_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/beacons_plugin) and [flutter_beacon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon) but I cannot seem to find any package that can receive these beacon broadcasts.

Has anyone been able to achieve this? If so, how?

Thank's @ukBaz - I am now seeing the Eddystone data.  However i am trying to get the namespace id and instance data from the device.

I am using a Minew D15N BLE beacon and printing out the data..

```
I/flutter (27645): device id: AC:23:3F:6A:FE:85, name: , type: BluetoothDeviceType.le found! rssi: -68
I/flutter (27645): advertisementData => localName: , txPowerLevel: null, connectable: false
I/flutter (27645): advertisementData -> serviceUuids length: 1
I/flutter (27645):      0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
I/flutter (27645): advertisementData -> manufacturerData length: 0
I/flutter (27645): advertisementData -> serviceData length: 1
I/flutter (27645): 0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb: [0, 232, 113, 28, 115, 246, 74, 253, 206, 7, 183, 227, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153]
```

I sometimes also receive this..

```
advertisementData -> manufacturerData length: 1
I/flutter (27645): 76: [2, 21, 144, 156, 60, 249, 252, 92, 72, 65, 182, 149, 56, 9, 88, 165, 26, 90, 234, 95, 39, 15, 204]
```

Based on this [documentation](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid) (not sure if this is right) I was trying this..

```
var naaa = ByteData.sublistView(manufacturerData, 2, 11);
```

But get this following error..

```
Uncaught Error: TypeError: null: type 'JSNull' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'
```

Here is a screen shot of the UID slot that i have setup to test..
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those packages look like they are just for iBeacon which uses manufacturer data in the advertising packet. For Eddystone it uses service data. The flutter_blue library give you access to the service data. https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue/latest/flutter_blue/AdvertisementData-class.html

The following answer shows how to scan and access the advertising data with flutter_blue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591662/7721752

Comment: Thank you - I am now seeing the Eddystone data with Flutter Blue.  Just looking at your previous responses to the other question and using your example, I am trying to get the UID Namespace ID and Instance and using the dartpad example unable to get it. I've updated the the question above with the data I am getting back - any chance you can see where I am going wrong!

Comment: It is the serviceData that you need to get bytes 2-11 for, not the manufacturerData. `[113, 28, 115, 246, 74, 253, 206, 7, 183, 227]` is your namesapce of `711c73f64afdce07b7e3`. The Eddystone service is `0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` or `feaa` for short.

Comment: Thank you - this was exactly what I was after